# Make thinner border for checkbox in winapi, WTL

Tags: c++, atl, wtl

I have the following checkbox, in visual studio I have set it's flat property to TRUE, I want to make it's rectangle border thinner. How could I do that in windows api, WTL, ATL ? C++. Is there some sort of message that I can send to the dialog in order to do this?

[image: I have the following checkbox]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose between control [styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), e.g. flat vs. non-flat, and you can use owner drawn controls (buttons) to take over visual presentation of the control. There is no dedicated message to adjust the thickness of the box.